# Blender: CUDA kernel compilation failed

Tags: nvidia, cuda, blender

I tried the solutions presented in this other question without any succes: [CUDA kernel compilation failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843507/cuda-kernel-compilation-failed)

Ie: I've tried running blender from terminal using sudo blender, installing g++5, changing kernel.cu. But nothing so far has worked

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS 64-bit

My graphic card is GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2 and I'm running Blender 2.76

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation    
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

This is what the terminal shows when trying to compile:

```
bernardo@Bernardo-asus:~$ sudo blender
connect failed: No such file or directory
Read new prefs: /home/bernardo/.config/blender/2.76/config/userpref.blend
read blend: /home/bernardo/Blender/donut10.blend
CUDA version 10.0 detected, build may succeed but only CUDA 6.5 is officially supported.
Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" -arch=sm_30 -m64 --cubin "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/kernels/cuda/kernel.cu" -o "/home/bernardo/.config/blender/2.76/cache/cycles_kernel_sm30_01D31872AEE3D1F297035A84954E3182.cubin" --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -I"/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel" -DNVCC -D__KERNEL_CUDA_VERSION__=100
/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/kernels/cuda/../../util_half.h(43): error: identifier "__float2half_rn" is undefined

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001291_00000000-6_kernel.cpp1.ii".
CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, using Ubuntu 16.04 and Cuda 9.2, it looks like tweaking the `util_half.h` file solves this particular issue, though it seems to take forever for the rest of the process.

You want to add the following include:

```
#include "cuda_fp16.h"
```

And comment out the line:

```
typedef unsigned short half;
```

The file is located at:

```
/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/util_half.h
```

The correct way is to simply download a newer version of blender, which works with Cuda 9 out of the box.